# Why barryvdh/laravel-dompdf Stuck or won't process HTML to PDF when using @font-face CSS?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, font-face, dompdf

When using dompdf library for generating html to pdf i don't find any problem. But when i adding the @font-face in the CSS and providing the .ttf file for "Courier New" Font, the dompdf was stuck at some process and it won't finish generating the pdf file.

i'm adding this line to my style

`@font-face {
      font-family: 'CourierNew';
      src: url('{{ asset('fonts/cour.ttf') }}');
 }`

and i'm putting the Courier New TrueType file at the public/fonts/ folder

My Project using :

1. Laravel : 5.8
2. PHP : 7.3.11
3. barryvdh/laravel-dompdf : ^0.8.4

Did anyone encounter such a problem or have a solution regarding this problem?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Capture]

Comment: Try using the path instead url `src: {{ public_path('fonts/cour.ttf') }} ;`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i've try it before, even i try making  it to a .css file and adding it using link in the head tag. Still no any luck. Btw the TrueType file was loaded when  i load it as normal html but when i generate the pdf, the dompdf was stuck.

Comment: maybe it's you are ussing quotes, since `{{ asset('fonts/cour.ttf') }}` and `{{ public_path('fonts/cour.ttf') }}` are already strings. I used [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/433#issuecomment-356538776) aproach and work fine for me. And maybe you have to set a caching folder to dompdf as Helioarch mentioned https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/433#issuecomment-431570201.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to temporarily increase the maximum execution with

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

// your pdf generation code

ini_restore('max_execution_time');
```

just to make sure that the issue is not that the pdf file you are trying to generate is too big and that the added time to load the font is enough to bring it over the execution time limit.

Comment: The content of the dom i want to generate to pdf wa just 1 paragraph "lorem ipsum". After increase the maximum execution the pdf file generated (took time 2 minute). But the font wasn't apply. Any Idea? (FYI, if i load the html without generating to pdf the font was apply to "Courier New").

Comment: Does it take equally as long if you just load the html? try to open the url generated from `{{ asset('fonts/cour.ttf') }}` in a browser and see how long it takes to load the font itself.. another thing to try is use `$dompdf->set_option('enable_font_subsetting', true);` before your `render()` call

Comment: i try to open the url generated from `{{ asset('fonts/cour.ttf') }}` and i load less than half second. i try using `$dompdf->setOptions(['enable_font_subsetting' => true]);` but it still generate the pdf in more than 2 minute without applying the font.

Comment: the last thing i can think of is to create the folder `\storage\fonts` and give dompdf permission over it with 755 or 777, as dompdf will use this for caching purpose..

Answer (score 0):

This maybe late, Hope this one works for someone.
My font files are in `public/fonts/`
I integrated with Laravel Blade and within that file in style tag you simply add the path as in normal css. And you also need to define the format, I got my font working like

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Product Sans';
        src: url('../fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
    }
```